# Get google search number of result in scala

Tags: scala, search, count

I am looking for a way to catch total number of results to a search on google (the "About **** results" field). I searched on google API but it seems that you can't get total number. Does anyone have informations that way ? How can I implement it in Scala (or any other language...) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML agility pack. Simply navigate to 
*"https://www.google.com/search?q=" + WhatYouWantToSearch*
and get content of it. After getting that urlcontent you can use code below

```
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(urlcontent);
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode hnc = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='resultStats']");
    string[] text = hnc.InnerHtml.Split(' ');
    return Convert.ToInt32(text[1].Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Trim());
```